# Can I use a similar rated charger if it has the same connecter pin size?

Tags: adapter, charger

I have a Lenovo Y510p laptop. It uses a 120W 19.5V 6.15A rated charger and the connecter pin is 5.5*2.5 mm. I can neither find an original Lenovo charger nor a compatible adapter with exact ratings in my locality. My question is can I use a 120W 19V 6.42A adapter for ASUS that has the same connecter pin size of 5.5*2.5 mm? I know the 0.5V difference won't be much and the current rating is >6.15A, so the adapter should work fine. But would it be possible to use it as I can't personally test one and I was thinking of ordering one online.

Answer (score 0):

If you are very certain that the size (shape), pin out arrangement, and polarity are the very same, then it will work. The 0.5 voltage reduction means it might take a little longer to charge.

We only use Lenovo adapters with our Lenovo ThinkPads.  Have you contacted Lenovo Support by phone?  There is a contact number on their support website.

Comment: Yes. I did check with the local service center and they said it will take at least 20 days. So I was looking for a replacement adapter. And yes, both have center positive polarity